# Best to load external resources from third parties or from your own server?

Tags: dns, resources

What is the best way to load external resources in order to speed up performance for your users?

Should one load for example jQuery from Google CDN through:

- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.js

Or is it better download the file, store and serve it on our own server?

Comment: One big advantage to using a CDN for commonly used files like jquery is that so many other webmasters do it, and therefore visitors already have it cached locally. This means they won't need to download it at all when arriving at your site.

Comment: While this question may be best suited for Pro Webmasters its unnecessary to create another question based on the same question found on another Stack Exchange with 'Great Answers' if you believe that your question is different from that on the Stack Overflow site then please adjust your question and make it more specific. Additionally I've forwarded this action to the other moderators for further review of my actions, there decision will be final and not for debate. Sorry and thanks. 

Answer (score 0):

I think its already answered in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) ,

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916430/is-better-use-cache-or-cdn) for more information

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Honestly thought this was more of a webmaster question than stack overflow!  Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: before asking question on any forum just Google it in deeply. you will get something